# Taperecorder wheel animation is not working after the Home button is pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.2, cabasicanimation

I am new in ios developement.I'm implementing Taperecorder project, in which i have some CABasicAnimations used to rotating wheel while recording audio and playing.Everything working fine(recording and playing)... but while recording an audio if i pressed home button again open the app backround recording process working fine wheel animation is not rotating..

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 2*M_PI];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
animation.duration = 4.0f;
animation.repeatCount = INFINITY;
[imageLeft.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
[imageRight.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SpinAnimation"];
```

Comment: when I press the home button on my iOS device, my application suspends (and animations -- and pretty much anything else -- stops).  Isn't that what should be happening in most iOS apps?

Comment: In that case, what you are expecting from iPhone/iPad ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addAnimation:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

}

//How to remove an observer for NSNotification

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
 - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
 {
      [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(your   animation method:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
 }
```